# difficulty displaying n number of records for pagination

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple pagination

html

```
<table id="mainTable">
<tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>yuu</td>
    <td>KitsuneJima</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>shishio</td>
    <td>Yokohama</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>seijiro</td>
    <td>Hokaido</td>
</tr>
</table>

<select id="hyoujiKensuuSentakushi">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

Now in place of hyoujiKensuu variable if you're going to replace it with 10, the table shows 10 records.

The first loading of the page, the table shows fine but when you hit next, no data will be display, only the table headers are left

what needs to be corrected?

Comment: Can you check if the value of variable hyoujiKensuu is always 10??

Comment: yes, i showed the variable value using alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was mainDraw function was not exec after the select element changes also as [Ejay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2219831/ejay) mentioned your jquery selector need fix

fixed [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xxSw/2/)

```
$('#hyoujiKensuuSentakushi').change(function () {
   hyoujiKensuu=parseInt($('#hyoujiKensuuSentakushi').val());
    mainDraw();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line

```
$('#mainTable tr:first,tr:gt(' + mainPage * hyoujiKensuu + '):lt(hyoujiKensuu)').show();
```

`hyoujiKensuu` is being treated as string instead of variable. Changing this line to

```
$('#mainTable tr:first,tr:gt(' + mainPage * hyoujiKensuu + '):lt(' + hyoujiKensuu + ')').show();
```

could fix your issue.